# Syntax highlighting issue in Vim where background is weird

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I just added the indentLine plugin for Vim, and I love it apart from this annoying syntax highlighting issue where the background of the dividing character stays black while the rest of the line is highlighted. It's really distracting for me. How can I fix this and make the background the same as the rest of the line, and the dividing character still visible?

[image]

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I've done both, and that issue points here :)